# spring boot webflux: avoid thread-blocking method calls in handler

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I am just getting started with `WebFlux` and the whole reactive paradigm and I am stuck on this:

```
@Component
public class AbcHandler {

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public Mono<ServerResponse> returnValue() throws IOException {

        Abc abc = objectMapper.readValue(new ClassPathResource("data/abc.json").getURL(), Abc.class);

        return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(abc));
    }
}
```

IntelliJ gives me warnings that `readValue()` and `toURL()` are thread-blocking method calls.

Can I ignore this or how else am I supposed to return a JSON structure I am reading in from the file system and mapping to a domain class?

I feel like this should somehow be done in an asynchronous manner or at least more "reactively".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you should wrap it in a fromCallable and make sure it gets run on its own thread.

[Blocking calls in reactor](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking)

```
@Autowire
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

public Mono<ServerResponse> fooBar() throws IOException {
    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> objectMapper.readValue(new ClassPathResource("data/Foo.json")
            .getURL(), Foo.class))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
            .flatMap(foo -> ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .bodyValue(foo));

}
```

Comment: aah perfect. Thank you very much for the example and pointing to the documentation!