# Can I use AtomicReference to get value of a Mono and code still remain reactive

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Sorry, I am new to reactive paradigm. Is is possible to use AtomicReference to get value of a Mono since reactive code can run asynchronously and different events run on different thread. Please see the sample below. I am also not sure if this piece of code is considered reactive

sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] a) {
  AtomicReference<UserDTO> dto = new AtomicReference<>();
  Mono.just(new UserDTO())
      .doOnNext(d -> d.setUserId(123L))
      .subscribe(d -> dto.set(d));
  UserDTO result = dto.get();
  dto.set(null);
  System.out.println(result); // produce UserDTO(userId=123)
  System.out.println(dto.get()); // produce null
}
```

Comment: It's possible if manipulation with the `AtomicReference` is done as a part of the reactive chain. However, in the above example, this is not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code snippet you have shared is not guaranteed to always work. There is no way to guarantee that the function inside `doOnNext` will happen before `dto.get()`. You have created a race condition.

You can run the follow code to simulate this.

```
    AtomicReference<UserDTO> dto = new AtomicReference<>();
    Mono.just(new UserDTO())
            .delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .doOnNext(d -> d.setUserId(123L))
            .subscribe(dto::set);
    UserDTO result = dto.get();
    System.out.println(result); // produces null
```

To make this example fully reactive, you should print out in the `subscribe` operator

```
Mono.just(new UserDTO())
        .doOnNext(d -> d.setUserId(123L))
        .subscribe(System.out::println)
```

In a more "real world" example, your method would return a `Mono<UserDTO>` and you would then perform transformations on this using `map` or `flatMap` operators.

** EDIT **

If you are looking to make a blocking call within a reactive stream this previous [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59218794/spring-boot-webflux-avoid-thread-blocking-method-calls-in-handler) contains a good answer

Comment: Thanks for answering. For some library I use, they dont actually return a Mono so that is why I want to use AtomicReference to so I have something to return without having to use .block(). But according to your answer, that would be possible due to race condition right?

Comment: I've added a link to another stack overflow question that should answer your question on how to make a blocking call in a reactive stream without have to call `block()`